# Why do I get an error trying to use Behaviors in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am trying to use Behaviors to handle the click event of a button in WPF.

```
<Button Content="Another Button" Width="100" IsEnabled="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>        
       ...
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

However I am getting this error message:

> The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Interaction'

Here is my namespace for i: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

And I have included the `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly. I presumed that was all that I need to do to use behaviors but obviously something is going wrong.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2010 you need to include these 3 references from Expression Blend: System.Windows.Interactivity, Microsoft.Expression.Controls and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a [known problem in Visual Studio 2008](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/487022/wpf-designer-creates-error-when-using-expression-blend-3-sdk-behaviors).  If you are using VS 2008, [this hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958017/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1719) may correct the issue (though I still had issues after installing it at times).

This behavior was corrected in Visual Studio 2010.